# Let $X$ be a 4-element set. What is the total number of possible binary relations on $X$?

Tags: set-theory

I want to know how the answer is worked out for this question.

> Let $X$ be a 4-element set. What is the total number of possible binary relations on $X$ ?

How is it possible to calculate this answer, I assumed the answer is $2^4$ which is 16, but 65,536 was the answer "they" gave.

Comment: Why did you assume the answer is $2^4$?

Answer (score 2):

A relation on $X$ is a subset of the Cartesian product $X \times X$ (i.e. a subset of the set of ordered pairs of elements of $X$).

So two questions arise: if $X$ has four members, what is the size of $X \times X$? [Hint, it is more than four!!]

And if the size of $X \times X$ is $n$, what how many different subsets of $X \times X$ are there?

Answer (score 2):

I think other answers are misconstruing what the OP probably meant (i.e. binary operation) with what the OP actually wrote (i.e. binary relation).

However, if the OP actually *did* mean relations, then the other answers are more suitable.

A binary operation on a set S is a function $f:S\times S\rightarrow S$. Now the number of functions from a finite set A (with cardinality a) to a finite set B (with cardinality b) is $b^a$.

Let the cardinality of $S$ be $n=4$. Then the cardinality of $S\times S$ is $n^2=16$.

So the number of binary operations on S is $n^{(n^2)}=4^{16}.$

Answer (score 0):

So, lets say $X = \{a, b, c, d\}$ is our 4 element set. Then let $R$ be a binary relation on $X$. This means that $R$ is a subset of $X \times X = \{(a, a), (a, b), (a, c), (a, d), \ldots, (d, a), (d, b), (d, c), (d, d)\}$. I think its clear to see that the size of $X \times X$ is 16. So then the question becomes, how many subsets of the set $X \times X$ are there? This is exactly asking, what is the size of the power set of $X \times X$?

From here, there are a few ways we can determine that $|P(X \times X)| = 65,536$. Hint, $65,536 = 2^{16}$.

> Given a set $A$ with $|A| = n$, $|P(A)| = 2^n$. So since $|X \times X| = 16$, $|P(X \times X)| = 2^{16}$

> Take the sum of all $k$ element subsets of $X \times X$. But if you don't know, $C(n, k)$, denotes exactly this, which is how many k element subsets of an n element set are there. We take $C(16, 0) + C(16, 1) + C(16, 2) + \ldots + C(16, 16)$. But by the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), this is exactly $2^{16}$.

Comment: The last spoiler is not brute force. The value $2^{16}$ is easily and popularly  obtained by putting x=1 in the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{16}$.

Comment: Oh yeah, your definitely correct @insipidintegrator. I didn't think of using [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to calculate it.